# It works with jquery 1.8.0 but not working in jquery 10.3 jqueryui - jeasyui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to insert an external html file into a panel/div. I'm using jquery and jeasyui to do this.

I used the `onload` function to create a panel and load external html file via jquery, as shown below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#tt').tabs({
                onLoad:function(panel){
                    var plugin = panel.panel('options').title;
                    panel.find('textarea[name="code-'+plugin+'"]').each(function(){
                        var data = $(this).val();
                        data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\n');
                        if (data.indexOf('\t') == 0){
                            data = data.replace(/^\t/, '');
                            data = data.replace(/\n\t/g, '\n');
                        }
                        data = data.replace(/\t/g, '    ');
                        var pre = $('<pre name="code" class="prettyprint linenums"></pre>').insertAfter(this);
                        pre.text(data);
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    prettyPrint();
                }
            });
        });
        function open1(plugin){
            if ($('#tt').tabs('exists',plugin)){
                $('#tt').tabs('select', plugin);
            } else {
                $('#tt').tabs('add',{
                    title:plugin,
                    href:plugin+'.html',
                    closable:true,
                    extractor:function(data){
                        data = $.fn.panel.defaults.extractor(data);
                        var tmp = $('<div></div>').html(data);
                        data = tmp.find('#content').html();
                        tmp.remove();
                        return data;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.10.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Any errors in console? What browser are you using?

Comment: shows like a basic html page.

Comment: If you're not going to tell me what errors you get, the only thing I can point out is that you have your `onload` script tag **before** your script includes. This will break your dependencies

Comment: i already tired it. but its wont work buddy..